# What will it do if I click "I hate hats" this link?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2012

What happens if I click the "I hate hats" link in the winter bash menu?

The mouse pointer tooltip showing "opt out of winter bash", what does it mean?

Comment: Winter Bash == Hats. So clicking it makes hats go away. What's confusing about it?

Comment: You won't get punished.

Comment: You'll be punished by being deprived of hats.

Comment: "opt out of winter bash" is pretty clear.

Comment: No reason for arrogance. This is a perfectly valid question, at least what concerns the 'I hate hats' part. Opt out should be pretty clear but it wouldn't surprise me if people in non English speaking countries never heard of it.

Comment: They log your IP address, triangulate your position and dispatch a crack squad of snipers.

Comment: @viktorb: SE is an english-speaking site, so we do expect the users to understand English to a certain level. That being said, we do help those who don't understand it -- the comments above aren't arrogant, they may not have realized that the OP has trouble with the word "opt out". That's all. Also, a simple Google search can tell you what "opt out" means.

Comment: @Manishearth yes a simple google search would have sufficed. The 'I hate hats' part on the other hand is likely to raise questions, although most users probably assume it's just for fun.

Comment: @viktorb I still don't think it is a valid question. The FAQ is clear.

Comment: They also could have named it "I hate fun!".

Comment: This is SO not TF2 $#%&!!

Comment: I'm English and Canadian (as if that were relevant) and i hate the stupid, confusing, waste-of-time-and-space that is "winter bash/hats"!

Comment: Why is this Q "closed as too localized"? Isn't the whole "winter bash/hats" thing the phenomenon that is "too localized" and "off topic"?

Comment: @MartinF because people hate fun, some even downvote all winter bash posts just because they don't like it. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars - Rather rude of you to state/assume that people who don't like your brand of fun hate fun in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [2022 Winter Bash FAQ](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/faq):

> ### I don’t want to see any hats! How do I get rid of them?
>
> When you click the snowflake icon in the top bar, a popup appears that has a link labeled "No hats for me, please". This will turn off all hat-related events on all sites for you. You won’t see people wearing hats, you won’t be alerted when you earn a hat, and you won’t be seen wearing a hat by any other users.

Comment: Note that once you opt-out you still have the option to opt back in (just click on the winter bash link again).